# Array destructuring in Python

Tags: python, lambda, rx-py

I am hoping to make `vals` in the last line be more clear.

```
import rx
from rx import operators as op

light_stream = rx.range(1, 10).pipe(
            op.with_latest_from(irradiance_stream),
            op.map(lambda vals: print(vals[0], vals[1])))  # light, irradiance
```

Is there something like array destructuring like this

```
op.map(lambda [light, irradiance]: print(light_intensity, irradiance))) # fake
```

or other ways to make the code clear? Thanks

Comment: You can just use `print(*vals)`. But if you goal is to make your code *clear* then just use a normal function and assign to local variables `light_intensity` and `irradiance`.

Comment: https://blog.itsyourpal.in/python-destructuring-assignments-simplify-your-python-code-like-never-before-4a502e858f9f

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python used to allow unpacking of iterable arguments in function signatures, which seems to be what you want for your `lambda` function. That feature was removed in Python 3, with the reasons set out in [PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

The main reason it was removed is that it messes up introspection a bit, as there is no good way to name the compound parameter that had been unpacked. If you take a normal parameter (in a normal function, not a one-line lambda), you can achieve the same results with a manual unpacking on a separate line (without messing up the original parameter name):

```
# def foo(a, (b, c), d):  # this used to be a legal function definition
def foo(a, bc, d):        # but now you must leave the two-valued argument packed up
    b, c = bc             # and explicitly unpack it yourself instead
    ...
```

Something else that might do what you want though is unpacking of values when you *call* a function. In your example, you can call `print(*vals)`, and the `*` tells Python to unpack the iterable `vals` as separate arguments to `print`. If `vals` always has exactly two values, it will be exactly like your current code.

Comment: big  loss in python3.