# Two or more positional arguments in lambda expression

Tags: python

Given following lists:

```py
arr = [1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4]
cmds = [[1, 3, 2], [3, 5, 1], [2, 7, 4]]
```

For each command in `cmds`, I want to obtain

```py
[arr[1:3][2], arr[3:5][1], arr[2:7][4]]
```

I tried:

```py
list(map(lambda x: arr[x[0]:x[1]][x[2]], cmds))
```

But could I possibly write a cleaner code than the above? I want to use 3 positional arguments i, j, k instead of x alone:

```py
list(map(lambda i, j, k: arr[i:j][k], cmds)) # This gives TypeError
```

Comment: A cleaner code would be `[arr[i:j][k] for i, j, k in cmds]`.

Comment: But isn't `arr[i:j][k]` the same as `arr[i+k]`?

Comment: `arr[1:3][2]` crashes, what's up with that?

Comment: @bereal Actually no, for example `arr[1+2]` wouldn't crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argument unpacking in function signatures has been removed in Python 3 (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55940225/array-destructuring-in-python)).

Here are some alternatives:

**Solution 1:**

If you want to get the same effect with clean code, @bereal's answer is a good choice:

```py
[arr[i:j][k] for i, j, k in cmds]
```

This is a for loop / list comprehension, so unpacking is allowed.

**Solution 2:**

If you insist on using `map`, you can do so with [nested lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21893219/20103413):

```py
list(map(lambda cmd: (lambda i,j,k: arr[i:j][k])(*cmd), cmds))
```

In the outer lambda, `cmd` is assigned an element in `cmds`, which corresponds to a list of length 3. The return value of this outer lambda is an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) that defines an inner lambda taking 3 arguments, which we pass in by unpacking the `cmd` argument from the outer lambda.

**Solution 3:**

This one's by @KellyBundy:

```py
list(map(lambda i,j,k: arr[i:j][k], *zip(*cmds)))
```

In this case, this is equivalent to

```py
arr = [1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4]
cmds = [[1, 3, 1], [3, 5, 1], [2, 7, 4]]

c1 = (1, 3, 2)
c2 = (3, 5, 7)
c3 = (1, 1, 4)
list(map(lambda i,j,k: arr[i:j][k], c1, c2, c3))
```

Comment: if you write `arr[i:j][k:k+1]` then it will get an empty list when the index is out of range instead of an exception, when there is a correct index then it will be a one element list instead.

Comment: You have a point, but it adds extra complexity to the code since each resulting element will need to be fetched with an additional if-else or for loop. Whether that should be implemented depends on OP's use case and whether the `cmds` variable can be trusted to provide valid information.